# How to write junit test in springboot ,when mail contain template

Tags: java, email, junit, spring-boot-test

how i can write junit for this mail code with template , here i am sending mail with template
this is my Service class Method:

```
    @Service
    public class ServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;
    @Value("${mail.send.to}")
    private String mailSendTo;
   
    public void sendMailOnEmailOptOut()
        throws MessagingException, IOException, TemplateException {
    String[] toAddressList = { mailSendTo };
    final String emailSubject = "email opt out testing";
    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, 
    MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    helper.setTo(toAddressList);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    model.put("user", "this is just for testing");
    configuration.getTemplate("email.template.html").process(model, stringWriter);
    String emailContent = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    helper.setText(emailContent, true);
    helper.setSubject(emailSubject);
    javaMailSender.send(message);
}
```

mail_send_to value come from property file
and this is email.template.html is in src->main->resources template folder

```
  <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, 
 maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>email opt-out testing</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div style="margin-top: 10px">Greetings, <b>${user} </b></div>
<div>welcome ! this is just for testing functionality of email </br></br></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java System Stubs to set environment variables for your unit tests, see this link
https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-stubs

Comment: can you explain more clearly with this example